# Unable to access MDX files from GraphQL in Gatsby Project

Tags: gatsby

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujq0DaSa58Y&t=835s) to build a blog from scratch using Gatsby.

I am getting stuck when I try to access the MDX files on the graphQL. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is what my GraphQL looks like: [My GraphQL, no allMDX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMvqX.png)

What the graphQL is supposed to look like: [Tutorial's GraphQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2Uke.png)

And my gatsby-config code:

```
module.exports = {
siteMetadata: {
  title: `Gatsby Crash Course`,
  author: {
    name: `James`,
    summary: `The Youtuber you are watching`,
  },
  description: `A simple Crash course .`,
  siteUrl: `http://localhost:8000/`,
  social: {
    twitter: `james_r_perkins`,
  },
},
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    options: {
      extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
    },
  },
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
      path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
      name: `blog`,
    },
  },
  `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  `gatsby-remark-images`,
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    options: {
      gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          options: {
            maxWidth: 1200,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
],
```

};

Answer (score 1):

You have two instances of the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` that may cause a collision of configurations. Use it like:

```
module.exports = {
siteMetadata: {
  title: `Gatsby Crash Course`,
  author: {
    name: `James`,
    summary: `The Youtuber you are watching`,
  },
  description: `A simple Crash course .`,
  siteUrl: `http://localhost:8000/`,
  social: {
    twitter: `james_r_perkins`,
  },
},
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
    options: {
      path: `${__dirname}/blog`,
      name: `blog`,
    },
  },
  `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  `gatsby-remark-images`,
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    options: {
      extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
      gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
        {
          resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          options: {
            maxWidth: 1200,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
],
};
```

Assuming that your `gatsby-source-filesystem` is properly set (your `.mdx` files are on `/blog`) now you should be able to see the GraphQL nodes. Run a `gatsby clean` before.